# Issues with "Case Else" taking priority over other "Case" conditions in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues where it appears `Case Else` is taking priority over other `Case` conditions.

The idea of the macro is depending on the sheet name, another separate macro is applied. I have about 8 sheets which have specific macros associated with each one and then for the remaining sheets (~20 of them) I use `Case Else` and apply a separate macro. This issue is that when there is a `Case Else` function at the end, none of the other `Case`s are applied. When I remove `Case Else` then the correct macro is applied to the sheets. It's as if `Case Else` becomes default/takes priority. I have tried alternate ways of applying separate macros below, but the issue still persists:

```
Sub Specify()

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        Select Case sht.Name
            Case "NB12", "NB15"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Alluvium"
            Case "NB24"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_BOCOBOML_GFA"
            Case "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_BOCOBOML_MIA"
            Case "Bore 47", "Bore 48"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_GFA"
            Case "Bore 4", "Bore 4a", "Bore 40"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West"
            Case "Bore 30"
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East"
            Case Else
                Application.Run "Groundwater_Macros.xlsm!limits_Monitoring_bores"
                Debug.Print sht.Name

        End Select
    Next sht

End Sub
```

```
Sub Specify_test()


    Dim Fun As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        Select Case sht.Name
            Case "NB12", "NB15"
                Call limits_Alluvium
            Case "NB24"
                Call limits_BOCOBOML_GFA
            Case "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31"
                Call limits_BOCOBOML_MIA
            Case "Bore 47", "Bore 48"
                Call limits_FracturedRock_GFA
            Case "Bore 4", "Bore 4a", "Bore 40"
                Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West
            Case "Bore 30"
                Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East
            Case Else
                Call limits_Monitoring_bores
                If Len(Fun) Then Fun = Fun & vbCr
                Fun = Fun & sht.Name
        End Select
    Next sht
    MsgBox Fun, vbInformation, "Sheets not processed"


End Sub
```

```
Sub Specify_test2()


    Dim Fun As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In Worksheets
        'Select Case sht.Name
            If sht.Name = "NB12" Or sht.Name = "NB15" Then
                limits_Alluvium
            ElseIf sht.Name = "NB24" Then
                limits_BOCOBOML_GFA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "NB16" Or sht.Name = "NB17" Or sht.Name = "NB19" Or sht.Name = "NB20" Or sht.Name = "Bore 31" Then
                limits_BOCOBOML_MIA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 47" Or sht.Name = "Bore 48" Then
                limits_FracturedRock_GFA
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 4" Or sht.Name = "Bore 4a" Or sht.Name = "Bore 40" Then
                limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West
            ElseIf sht.Name = "Bore 30" Then
                limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East
            Else
                limits_Monitoring_bores
            End If
        'End Select
    Next sht

End Sub
```

```
Sub Specify_test3()

Dim Fun As String
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In Worksheets
    Select Case sht.Name
    Case "NB12", "NB15": Call limits_Alluvium
    Case "NB24": Call limits_BOCOBOML_GFA
    Case "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31": Call limits_BOCOBOML_MIA
    Case "Bore 47", "Bore 48": Call limits_FracturedRock_GFA
    Case "Bore 4", "Bore 4a", "Bore 40": Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_West
    Case "Bore 30": Call limits_FracturedRock_MIA_East
    Case Else: Call limits_Monitoring_bores
    End Select
Next sht

End Sub
```

I have troubleshooted the sheet names. i don't think that is the issue as when `Case Else` is omitted, the correct macro is applied.

Comment: `Case Else` cannot take priority. It's only executed if none of the above cases are not applicable. IOW, it's the code of last resort, which means that when it executes all other options have been tested and found to not be suitable. This would be the time for you to start stepping through the code in the debugger to find out where your code logic is flawed.

Comment: @KenWhite then how come the other ones are applied correctly when ```Case Else``` is omitted?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't explain your posted observations?  What is the relationship between the sheet names and the called methods in the Case statements?  Does each one operate on a specific sheet with a fixed name?  How does the called code know which sheet you're currently looking at in your Select block?

Comment: That's what you need to figure out in the debugger. It's impossible for `Case Else` to take priority, period. You have a logic error somewhere else.

Comment: `For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` or maybe `For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` ?  Always pays to be specific.

Comment: @TimWilliams The sheets names are fixed. So depending on the sheet name, it calls on the correct macro which then applies appropriate limits to the data for analysis. Its supposed to be an automated process. So for example, someone downloads and opens up "Bore 4" for data analysis (data is constantly updated, therefore the sheet for analysis changes). They then run the macro which applies the correct limits so that the data can be analysed. Different bores (for example) have different limits therefore I have an appropriate macro for them

Comment: Try adding `Debug.Print "|" & sht.Name & "|"` just before the `Select Case` then look in the Immediate Window to see if the results are what you expected.  It might show you are iterating the wrong workbook (as others have tried to tell you) or it might show issues like wrong case, or leading/traing spaces .

Comment: Consider just unrolling that loop into a series of explicitly ordered procedure calls. Unclear why one would need to invoke the same macro 3 times without any parameters, just because 3 sheets exist with particular given names... something isn't adding up, are the 2nd and 3rd runs expected to be any different from the 1st?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'll try explain the situation as best as possible. So there are a number of bores (water) that need to be analysed. Each bore has its own set of limits associated to it. Some bores share the same limits. Therefore, depending on the name of the sheet (bore name) the correct macro (which applies limits) is called upon. So "NB16", "NB17", "NB19", "NB20", "Bore 31" all share the same limits, therefore I use ```Call limits_BOCOBOML_MIA``` and then the other sheets have the appropriate limits applied by calling different Macros

Answer (score 3):

Execution unexpectedly falling back to `Case Else` is a symptom, a clue.

> ```
> For Each sht In Worksheets
> ```

Exactly which specific workbook this `Sheets` object belongs to, depends on too many things to work *reliably*.

If the code is in the `ThisWorkbook` module, then we should make that explicit:

```
For Each sheet In Me.Worksheets
```

But that code can't be in the `ThisWorkbook` module, or we wouldn't be here, so...

If we're in any other module and we want to iterate the sheets in `ThisWorkbook`, then we'd use the workbook's *code name* as a qualifier:

```
For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
```

If we're in any module other than `ThisWorkbook`, then `Worksheets` alone is essentially `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, and if we don't **know** what workbook we're iterating sheets from, there's a chance we're not iterating the sheets of the workbook we thought was the active one ;-)

There's a [Rubberduck inspection](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveWorkbookReference) that can find all such implicit/unqualified `ActiveWorkbook` references for you (disclaimer: I manage the Rubberduck project).

Comment: yes the macro is located on a separate excel file to the file for analysis

Comment: In that case the code that opens the other workbook needs to hold a reference to that workbook, and pass it around to everyone that needs it. e.g. `Set book = Application.Workbooks.Open(path)`, and then `book` can be used further down that scope, or passed as a `Workbook` argument - *that* is the object you want to use as a qualifier.

Comment: FWIW I hope none of these macros involve reading and writing any global state/variable: the execution order is unknown at compile-time, global state would be very bug-prone.

Comment: I open each workbook manually. So for example: I open the file with the macro, then I open excel file that I want to analyse. Then while being on that file, I use a key shortcut which calls the macro from the macro file and runs in on the file for analysis.

Comment: So the role of the macro book is to basically be an add-in? Why not just make it that? That way it'll never be the ActiveWorkbook

Comment: I'm new to this. Just looked it up and will do that

Comment: Even using ```ThisWorkbook.Worksheets``` and using it as an add-in, the issue still persists

Comment: as stated in the main comments above, Try adding `Debug.Print "|" & sht.Name & "| - Length: " & len(sht.Name)` just before the `Select Case` - What you think should match the case is not matching for some reason, and the debug window will then show you what it's attempting to match. The pipe symbols are there so you can see if there are leading or trailing spaces... Check the length too in order to see if there might be two spaces in a row that you cannot see. Sometimes you need to add code simply to help you debug an issue that is not obvious.

Comment: Another technique would be to add a `Stop` in the `Case Else` so that you can see when your conditions are not being met, and can compare closely the reason why. It's not a bug in VBA as you seem to be suggesting.

Comment: @Zacchini in an add-in, `ThisWorkbook` refers to the add-in project's host Excel workbook, just like it does in a macro-enabled workbook. Your code works against whatever workbook happens to be active, and if that workbook doesn't have any sheet with these names, then the `Case Else` is the branch that gets to run - *as it should be*.